# Creating SP specific to a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Every time I create a stored procedure it is defaulting to the "master" database.  How do I make a SP specific to database "uploads"?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testInsert2
AS
INSERT INTO [uploads].dbo.[aspnet_uploads]
(userID, fileName, userName)
VALUES 
('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3')
```

Comment: it is considered bad practice to reference database in your code (sp, functions); in your case it's the `[uploads].` part.

Comment: @Denis I agree with that in general, of course it always depends, but this makes it very hard to make a copy of the database with a different name to isolate for testing etc. Now all of your procedures still reference the primary copy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be in the context of that database.

```
USE uploads;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testInsert2
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.[aspnet_uploads](userID, fileName, userName)
      VALUES('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3');
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reconnect the server it occurs. You can try as like this

```
USE [database_name]
GO
Create Procedure [procedure_name]
AS
```